# Android FCM total sent notifications much higher compared to received

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

We've noticed in the firebase console that under the cloud messaging report the total number of push notifications that are sent is much higher than the ones received. It can be as 15k push notifications sent and only 3.5k received or 7.6k sent and 2.6k received. Is there a reason for the difference being this much? We are trying to determine if there is an issue on our end maybe with the payload or how the Firebase SDK was implemented in the app.

Comment: You might want to read https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that does not help with anything. We are not able to reproduce this as in,  we will always get a push when providing a push token which the app sent to our server. That's why I ask about if this difference is normal. Based on that guide and based on what it is described as "device inactive".

Comment: Hi @AlexFreeman Any Update about the same?

Comment: I've asked around, its just related to device status. Like network, snooze state, user preference when it comes to push notifications. It does not seem like there is anything that can be done to control it, not from our end anyway.